# Как сделать такую настройку для Apache 2.2.22?

Tags: apache, nginx, администрирование

Есть веб-сервер nginx на CentOS 6.5, настроен следующим образом:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name ~^nginx\.(?<tag>.+)\.local;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/html/$tag;
        index index.php  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           /var/www/html/$tag;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Т.е. если через веб-морду идет запрос на хост nginx.developer.local, то nginx его автоматом редиректит сюда: /var/www/html/developer

А как сделать так же для apache 2.2.22 (Debian 7)?

Comment: Появилась необходимость иметь оба веб-сервера иметь в постоянной готовности для разработки проектов, поэтому обустраиваю их симметрично.

Comment: что именно в настройке apache2 надо повторить ?

Comment: Редирект в зависимости от запрошенного хоста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

где-то я здесь сто лет назад я давал пример как такое сделать через rewrite rules, [вот](/questions/191412)

и вот еще способ я как-то делал, забыл уже :)

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/default
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/hosts/site.%1/webroot
```

как поменять под ваши нужды поди сообразите, нужен модуль

[`mod_vhost_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html)

[вот еще статья на русском про `mod_vhost_alias`](http://www.softtime.ru/info/apache.php?id_article=103)

Comment: Спасибо, большое, в моем случае заработало так:
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%2/